# How to use custom JSON converter for a specific .Net Framework Type

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm working with JSON.NET library.

I want to write a custom `JsonConverter` that converts a `Dataset` class to JSON. I have done the Converter, but I don't know how to tell JSON.NET serializer to use my custom converter to serialize objects of type `Dataset`.

**Is it possible? and how it can be done?**

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base

Comment: Or you can see [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/customizing-the-converter-for-json-net) and [Here](http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results/)

Comment: thanks about the links but non of them can be used in this case. all of the links above define their own class basically. please consider that I CAN'T use json attributes on .Net Framework's classes!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

[DataTable JSON Serialization in JSONNET](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer)

But with some changes you can use it for `DataSet` too.

I hope that will help you.